# From owin middleware, how to know the controller name/type?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, owin, katana

I am creating an owin middleware. From IOwinContext, is it possible to know what controller is it going to hit or has hit ?

I can see that its has request uri but I can't find routeData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't know.  The idea of OWIN, and middleware in general is to be unaware of the rest of the pipeline.  It is designed to be independent of the server or the application.
If you really need to know this information, you are probably better off looking at something specific to ASP.Net (whether Web API or MVC) to handle that information, such as a filter.

Hope that helps.